# CSS not working at all

Tags: html, css

I am thinking it has to do with the link somehow but am lost. I am 3 hours in to what should have been less than a minute. I am using bootstrap as a framework. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 table">
         <table class="table table-striped">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td><form method="GET"><input type="text" name="product-name[]" value="product name" class="form-control"disabled></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" value="description" class="form-control"disabled></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" size="1" value="qty" class="form-control"disabled></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price-unit[]" size="2" value="price" class="form-control"disabled></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sub-total[]" size="2" value="subtotal" class="form-control"disabled></td>
             </tr>
              </tbody>
               </table>
                </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.form-control[disabled], fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
      cursor: default;
    }
```

Here is the Head:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title> Submit Payment | SeaItManageIt</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQVMap -->
    <link href="../vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="../build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../build/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
```

Comment: are there any errors in your browser console? that will tell you if the link href is 404'ing.

Comment: Nope no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code seems to work fine. Press the "run code snippet" below and see for yourself:**

The default cursor is the one showing as expected of your CSS code.

```css
.form-control[disabled], fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
      cursor: default;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title> Submit Payment | SeaItManageIt</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQVMap -->
    <link href="../vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="../build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../build/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

<div class="col-xs-12 table">
         <table class="table table-striped">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td><form method="GET"><input type="text" name="product-name[]" value="product name" class="form-control"disabled></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" value="description" class="form-control"disabled></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" size="1" value="qty" class="form-control"disabled></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price-unit[]" size="2" value="price" class="form-control"disabled></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sub-total[]" size="2" value="subtotal" class="form-control"disabled></td>
             </tr>
              </tbody>
               </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: Which is weird because I can not get it to work on my localhost at all. I am trying to put the styling in the style.css file which is the last linked one so it should have importance over the other files.

Comment: The CSS `cursor:default` will display the "arrow" cursor, and that's what your code is currently displaying. Is this NOT what you want? What kind of cursor do you want to display exactly?

Comment: I wanted the arrow one but the code is fine I figured out but the link is not working yet the inspect shows that it is pulling data from those files. I solved it a crappy way by just using another CSS file.